# Running script on elevated cmd.exe

Tags: windows, cmd, shellexecute, wsh, runas

How do I ran a script after I open a command window using the below script?

```
Set objSh = CreateObject("Shell.Application")
objSh.ShellExecute "cmd.exe", "uac" , "", "runas", 1
```

For example, how do I run `ipconfig` as an admin using the above script?

Answer (score 0):

If you specify the `/c` switch, then `cmd.exe` will carry out the specified command and then terminate.

So, for example:

```
Set objSh = CreateObject("Shell.Application")
objSh.ShellExecute "cmd.exe /c ipconfig", "uac" , "", "runas", 1
```

Alternatively, you could use the `/k` switch, which works exactly the same way, except it keeps the command prompt on the screen once your command finishes executing.

Comment: the /c switch doesn't work when the object is "Shell.Application", it only works for "Wscript.Shell" objects.  I dont know the "runas" function/argument using wscript.shell.

Comment: Does `objSh.ShellExecute "ipconfig", "uac" , "", "runas", 1` work?

Comment: I'm not sure if that works, but i do know this works: objSh.ShellExecute "cmd.exe", " /c ipconfig", , "runas", 1          the second parameter are the arguments to the function.  Thanks for the reply btw